# How to append value " select " to the Select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I want add "All" option to the existing dropdown as a first option. Pls help me

```js
if(own != null)
{
    var ar = own.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",");
    var output = $("#status_type");
    output.empty();

    for(var i=0;i<ar.length/2;i++)
    {
        output.append("<option value='" + $.trim(ar[i*2+1]) + "'>" + $.trim(ar[i*2+1]) + "</option>");  
        //alert ("val " +$.trim(ar[i*2+1]));
    }
}
```

I want "All" to be the first option in select dropdown

Comment: Why not do another `append` right before the `for` loop starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `empty()` use `.html()` and pass the `html` of the All Option. This will clear the `select` first then will add all option and then will add other options, and will save you an unnecessary `.empty()` operation.

```
if(own != null)
            {
                var ar = own.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",");
                var output = $("#status_type");

                output.html('<option value="'+all+'">All</option>');

                for(var i=0;i<ar.length/2;i++)
                {
                    output.append("<option value='" + $.trim(ar[i*2+1]) + "'>" + $.trim(ar[i*2+1]) + "</option>");  
                    //alert ("val " +$.trim(ar[i*2+1]));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You can add ALL option just right after emptying the `output` variable as shown below -

```
if(own != null)
            {
                var ar = own.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",");
                var output = $("#status_type");
                output.empty();
                output.append("<option value='ALL'></option");//add here
                for(var i=0;i<ar.length/2;i++)
                {
                    output.append("<option value='" + $.trim(ar[i*2+1]) + "'>" + $.trim(ar[i*2+1]) + "</option>");  
                    //alert ("val " +$.trim(ar[i*2+1]));
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
             $('#mysampledropdown').empty();
            $.each(response.d, function(key, value) {
                $("#mysampledropdown").append($("<option></option>").val(value.ID).html(value.text));

            });
              $('<option>').val("").text('--ALL--').prependTo('#mysampledropdown');
```